# how to get double-quoted json body in python?

Tags: json, python-3.7, rest

I have such code in python3 to try to load the json data from "sample.json" file, and then to make a post REST API call.

```
import json

with open('sample.json' ) as request_file:
        post_data = json.load(request_file)
print(requst_data)

headers = {'X-CSRFToken': '...', 'Cookie': '...', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Referer': MY_URL}
response = requests.post(MY_URL, data=request_data, headers=headers)
print(response.json())
```

But the api call failed for

```
{'msg': ['JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)']}
```

What I have realized is in the "sample.json", everything is double-quoted, but after this json.load() call, the "request_data" is of single-quoted json value.

Is there anyway I can work around this issue ?

Comment: The problem is more to do with the response itself - since the error occurs when you try to process the response as JSON, i.e. `print(response.json())`. What API is this, is it one you wrote? What is it meant to respond with? Also what do `print(response.ok)` and `print(response.status_code)` print?

Comment: The print(response.ok) returns back "False", and print(response.status_code) is giving 400 error.

Comment: I have tried 2 more things. a) I have also used the same URL, same header value to try to make a GET API CALL in python, and it works. b) For the same Post Call, of the same Headers setting, I was able to make the Post call through the curl command. So it seems to me it was the request body in my original call that causes the failure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but if I to update the header as this:

```
headers = {'X-CSRFToken': '...', 'Cookie': '...', 'Referer': MY_URL}
```

which is to remove the `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` part, the call works.

Comment: The `Content-type` header in this case tells the API what format the body of the request is in. Its possible the data you were sending wasn't in JSON format. I can see 3 difference variables in your original code - `post_data`, `requst_data` and `request_data`. So maybe the data you were sending wasn't actually JSON-encoded. You need to be consistent with your naming. There wouldn't normally be an issue with passing that header, assuming the data is compatible with it - otherwise, you'd be confusing the API.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, when I was editing this message. I am only using one data valuable in my script. Anyway, if I look into the "sample.json" file, everything is double quoted. but the print-out from the script execution is of single-quoted format. And If I am using the updated header, the call can be executed.

Comment: In that case, best to leave the `Content-type` header out. Its best practise to also use double quotes for the headers. Is the concern that when you print the response, it shows single quotes? Because that's not really a problem, its just how Python shows it when you print it out.